# How to synchronize bucket and database of two heroku apps?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, amazon-s3

I have two asp.net apps - 'production' and 'show'. Their codebase are the same (the same Git repository from which they are deployed). Both have their own PG database and S3 bucket.

I wish that every day the postgres database of 'show' would be restored from backup of 'production' database (daily backups are scheduled). Also, whole bucket of 'production' will be replicated to bucket of 'show' app.

I tried to do that from code, but didn't found the way to run pg:restore
I tried to do that with Heroku Scheduler, but documentation is poor, so I'm stucked.
Maybe it is possible to do with bash script, but how to run it once a day?

Answer (score 1):

Use a bash script. Then use the Heroku Scheduler to make it run once every day.

I use node.js, but I do believe you can run bash scripts the same way inside the Heroku Scheduler.

[image]

I have the bash script located inside my bin folder, in the path: `/bin/runGetMonthlyTransactions`. Don't worry about the 'Monthly' wording. Just my script needs to run everyday but doesn't report anything until the beginning of the month.

Comment: I've did it. But my script requires to use 'heroku pg:copy'. It tells me that heroku command not found. The same was with aws cli, but I've installed it via buildpack aswcli. How to install heroku CLI or how to do pg:copy without it?